# Problemas con las librerias

Tags: python

Intento utilizar *matplotlib* pero me da error todo el rato, ¿hay alguna forma de desinstalar todo lo que tengo de *Python* para volver a instalarlo todo de 0?.

Cambie de ordenador hace años y tengo librerías y programas por varias carpetas diferentes.

**Mi código:**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from  matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib import style
from math import *
from matplotlib import figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation


root= tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title=('graficador')
ta=root.geometry('1000x700')
style.available('fivethirtyeigth')

fig=figure()
axl=fig.add_subplot(111)

canvas=FigureCanvasAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, 
expand=1)#expande los ejes xy hasta 1
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, 
expand=1)

plt.show()
```

**El error que me da esta vez es:**

> ```
> style.available('fivethirtyeigth')
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
> ```

Anteriormente me decía que el problema estaba en que *matplotlib* no contenía figure.

Estoy empezando en esto y necesito hacer un ejecutable que reciba un documento.txt con una serie de valores y el ejecutable mediante un botón me genere la gráfica permitiéndome marcar con el cursor los puntos que quiera en ella.

Comment: Si hay forma, pero estás seguro de que el error se solucionará reinstalando? Podrías agregar el/los mensajes de error en la pregunta junto al código que te da error?

Comment: Perdonad pero no sabía que había que editar la pregunta para añadir más información. Hay alguna solución para que localice bien las librerías al intentar importarlas?